# Natvis problem after reinstalling VS2017 on different folder

Tags: visual-studio-2017, natvis

After reinstalling VS2017 on different folder, when I compile an old project I get an error about a missing natvis file (which now is on a different path).

I searched inside the VC++ project files and my user profile but it is not there.

Where natvis information is stored?

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\std_json.natvis'

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it is inside .vcxproj file but it does not show in explorers.